# Как присвоить дату дублированому листу?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Вот такой скрипт

```
   function myFunction() {
       var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
       spreadsheet.getRange('D7').activate();
       spreadsheet.duplicateActiveSheet();
       spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setName(new Date());
       spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('СЕГОДНЯ'), true);
       spreadsheet.getRange('A2:H7').activate();
       spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
   };
```

в итоге я получаю: `Wed Jan 13 2021 06:48:25 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)`

Как получить название в формате `DD/MM/YYYY`?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [formatDate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String))
Например, так:

```
var dateString = Utilities.formatDate(
   new Date(),
   SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), 
   "dd/MM/yyyy");

// А потом кусок вашего кода:
spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setName(dateString );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+2", 'dd/mm/yyyy');
```